# Conditionally print an error message

Tags: r

I have a function that calculates the mean values for a data frame and I would like to add a an error message if the type of variable is not compatible with calculating a mean, i.e. an ID column of type character. 
so far I have:

```
meanvals <-function(i, data) {ifelse(typeof(i)=="integer" | typeof(i)=="numeric", mean(df[,i])/100, warning( "is an invalid type of variable"))}
```

but this is not recognizing numeric variables. I would also like to include what value of i is not numeric but can't figure out how to have it change for each value of i.

Comment: `ifelse` is for vectorized stuff. This is an appropriate time to use `if(){}`. Btw, `warning()` will give a warning, not an error. Use `stop()` for an error message.

Comment: And unless `i` is a list, every  element of `i` will be the same type.

Comment: Also , please _don't_ redefine the `mean` function. If you need a different func then give it a different name. I think examples of seriously bad programming practices deserve a downvote.

Comment: my apologies, I've only just started coding so I don't know the nuances of good programming yet. thank you so much for pointing it out, 42.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish generating a list of means or "not valid" results is with an `apply()` function in base R.

```
data(mtcars)
# add rownames as a character variable to data frame 
mtcars$carName <- rownames(mtcars)

lapply(mtcars,function(x){
     if(typeof(x) == "character") " is not numeric."
     else mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
})
```

...and the output:

```
$mpg
[1] 20.09062

$cyl
[1] 6.1875

$disp
[1] 230.7219

$hp
[1] 146.6875

$drat
[1] 3.596563

$wt
[1] 3.21725

$qsec
[1] 17.84875

$vs
[1] 0.4375

$am
[1] 0.40625

$gear
[1] 3.6875

$carb
[1] 2.8125

$carName
[1] " is not numeric."
```